# Why did Community make this post community wiki?

Tags: support, specific-question, community-wiki

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38357/1709587) has [only been edited once](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38357/revisions), and has only three answers, and yet:

> Post Made Community Wiki by Community♦
>   occurred Nov 25 '08 at 12:32

Why did this occur?

Comment: The community is trolling you.

Comment: @JoshC I just spent quite a while compiling an answer to that question without noticing it was CW, and now I'll never get my precious rep. *Sniff.*

Comment: We all knew it would happen eventually @JoshC.

Comment: @JoshC In case you haven't noticed, the, uh, 'edit' that was made to the question is also somewhat suspect. I suspect that's the result of a tag merge subsequent to the edit, though?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears that long, long ago when a user ticked the "community wiki" checkbox on their post (which can no longer be done for questions), it just got attributed to the Community user rather than listing their name for it (or maybe they didn't get recorded at the time and are just *now* getting attributed to Community). This is also demonstrated by [this community wiki question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/112964/revisions) which was made community wiki by the author the moment it was created.

Comment: 1+ For removing the wiki status.